# Iniciar sesión al registrarse en Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

me gustaría saber como podría hacer que un usuario al registrarse correctamente, se le inicie sesión de forma automatica en un proyecto de Symfony.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalmente lo que se hace es lanzar el evento de login antes creándolo, algo así:

```
private function loginUser(Request $request, UserInterface $user) : void
{
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);

    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN, $event);
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias !